# How to get a username from response object using Auth0 Lock?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, authentication, auth0

The question is how to get username, which I used to login, back from response object?

I'm creating the Auth0Lock instance by following code:

```
this._lock = new Auth0Lock(AUTH_CONFIG.clientId, AUTH_CONFIG.domain, AUTH_CONFIG.options);
```

and then I subscribe on "authenticated" event:

```
this._lock.on('authenticated', authResult => {
  this._lock.getUserInfo(authResult.accessToken, function(error, profile) {

        console.log('profile', profile); // --> undefined

        if (error) {
          // Handle error
        }

  });
})
```

I'm logging in by following credentials:

username: john@gmail.com  password: 123456

I want to be able to see 'username: john@gmail.com' somewhere in authResult object.
But unfortunately I don't see.

Should I add something in Auth0lock options?

P.S.  I've added following code inside the handler of "authenticated" event, but it returns undefined for profile.

Comment: Check step 2 of the documentation: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11

Comment: When I'm calling this.getUserInfo(authResult.accessToken, function(error, profile){ console.log('profile', profile) })
I'm getting error: Uncaught TypeError: _this2.getUserInfo is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I've just added scope: 'openid' into "auth" property of options

```
options: {
  ...
  auth: {
    ...
    scope: 'openid'  <---
  }
}
```